# Nginx behind Traefik Docker Swarm mode real ip

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode, traefik

I'm using Traefik as a reverse proxy in front of nginx service on a docker swarm environment. Here's my docker-stack.yml:

```
traefik:
    image: traefik
    command: -c /dev/null --web --docker --docker.swarmmode --docker.watch --docker.domain=domain --logLevel=DEBUG
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
       - app
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]

nginx:
    image: nginx
    networks:
      - app
    deploy:
      labels:
        traefik.port: 80
        traefik.docker.network: app
        traefik.frontend.rule: "Host:app.domain"
```

Everything works fine but I need the real client IP in my Nginx access log, instead I get something like 10.0.1.37

How get I can the real client ip?

Thanks,

Answer (score 10):

This issue was discussed on [github #614](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/614).

> When the upstream service receives requests forwarded from Traefik, the `X-Forwarded-For` header contains an IP address from the overlay network, not the actual client address.

To overcome this, you can use the new way of [declaring service ports in docker-compose >=3.2 (**LONG SYNTAX**)](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports).

Then you ensure that traefik is attached to host network and will send the right `X-Forwarded-For` header (see below `mode: host` for the 80 port):

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  traefik:
    ...
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - "443:443"
    ...
```

Finally, you have to change the nginx log_format in the `http {} section`. That can be done through volume binding of a `nginx.conf` configuration file:

```
nginx:
  ..
  volumes:
    - /data/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

you'd have `nginx.conf` with this:

```
http {
  ...
  log_format main '$http_x_forwarded_for - $remote_user [$time_local] '
  '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
  '"$http_user_agent"' ;
```

Tested on an AWS ec2, the `traefik_nginx` service (I called my stack `traefik`) logs like this:

```
$ docker service logs -f traefik_nginx
...
traefik_nginx.1.qpxyjheql5uk@xxx    | 82.253.xxx.xxx - - [20/Jun/2017:08:46:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.104 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, that can work for now. I think mode 'host' prevent Swarm routing mech: if a have 2 nodes in my swarm only 1 node is actually exposing traefik right?

Comment: I think you're right (did not check it), but as the routing mesh uses ingress network (overlay network that we bypass using the `host` network), traefik should only be exposed on the host it's deployed to. If you test it, i'd be glad if you can update me.